# Cant pass array of objects to setPeople function in React

Tags: reactjs

I have another file of data.js that i'm calling it in my index.js. I know I will get data if I pass it in useState directly like this below.

```
const [people, setPeople] = useState(data);
```

But I want to keep the above state null at the start rather than passing data.

```
const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
```

But rather than accessing data this way I want to directly pass it in my setPeople. Is it possible to do that? Something like this. So that it can be accessed in people and can be iterated.

```
setPeople([...people,{data}])
```

**Index.js**

```
import React, { useState, useReducer } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';
import { data } from '../../../data';
// reducer function

const Index = () => {
  const [name,setName]= useState('');
  const [modal, showModal] = useState(false);
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = ((e)=>
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPeople([...people,{data}])
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type='text' value={name} onChange={((e)=>setName(e.target.value))} />
        <button type='submit'>Add</button>
      </form>
      {
        people.map((person,index)=>{
          return(
            <div key={index}>
              <h2>{person.name}</h2>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
};

export default Index;
```

**data.js**

```
export const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'john' },
  { id: 2, name: 'peter' },
  { id: 3, name: 'susan' },
  { id: 4, name: 'anna' },
];
```

Comment: `data` is an array of objects, so you probably want to _spread_ its contents using the spread syntax: `setPeople([ ...people, ...data ])`

Comment: You can try this also - ` setPeople((prev) => [...prev, ...data])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass this additional data to **setPeople** in the same way which you pass current people - use spread syntax.

```
setPeople([ ...people, ...data ])
```

Also if you want to depend on current `people` state you should pass callback which always provide you correct value which sometimes can't not happen if you depend on `people`.

```js
setPeople(( prevPeople ) => [ ...prevPeople, ...data ])
```

**UPDATE**

```
const Index = () => {
  const [name,setName]= useState('');
  const [modal, showModal] = useState(false);
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  useEffect( () => {
     setState(data) // this will be added only once when component mounted
  }, [])

  const handleSubmit = ((e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setPeople(( prevPeople ) => [ ...prevPeople, { id: ?, name: "Only one new person" } ])
  })

  return (
    <div>
      { /* your jsx */ }
    </div>
  )
};
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    const peoplesIds = people.map( p => p.id )
    const notIncludedData = data.filter( obj => ! peoplesIds.includes( obj.id )  )

    setPeople( prev => [ ...prev, ...notIncludedData, { id: 100, name: "new guy" } ] )
  }
```

Comment: There's another problem now. It prints all the data of data.js every time I add a new item. It wasn't happening when i pass passing it directly in useState(data).

Comment: So you probably want to pass data only once on the beginning ? If yes you can try with useEffect.. check update section in my answer.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly what you want to achieve.. can you explain it to me once again ? You want to add data each time when you click submit or you want to add them only when component is initialized ?

Comment: Thankyou. I'm close but bit far. What i'm trying to achieve is. That at the start it should display nothing when I click on submit. It displays all data of file data.js. When I add a new item it adds it below it and so on. Like it was working when I passing passing it in useState(data).

Comment: In your first answer it was adding data.js data again and again on adding any new item. In your second answer it shows data.js already. I want to display it after submit.

Comment: I just want to display data.js on submit. When I click on submit it should add new data below it and keeps on going. But the only problem with [..people,..data] was that it was displaing whole data.js data again and again on adding new items.

Comment: Check update 2 .. I believe that now it's what you want.. I hope :)

Comment: Also now you should remove previous useEffect

Comment: Now on submit it display it for 1 second and refreshes the screen. This message appears for a second SharedArrayBuffer will require cross-origin isolation as of M91, around May 2021

Comment: I tested it and nothing like it happened. Can you provide what your code looks like now on codesandbox or similar platform ?

Comment: e.preventDefault(); This was missing. This was causing that error Thankyou All sorted. You have been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this at `handleSubmit`

```js
setPeople([...people,...data])
```